# How to create a directory with an update-site from "Install new software..."

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, p2

I'm creating an update-site to install some features for Eclipse to extend. I have a zip that contains executable that I would like to have installed in a specific directory under the root. Is it possible to create a folder under the root install location and drop contents in there?

```
< Install_location >/myFolder/
```

Comment: See [Adding files to the Root of a Build](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm) in the Eclipse help

Comment: And see [Tycho's support for root files](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/FAQ#How_do_I_include_rootfiles.3F)